# How to get proper data when using blade components and alpinejs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, alpine.js

I'm new in components and alpine in laravel. I have data from controller `$positions`.

```
$positions = [
        ['id' => 1, 'content' => 'king'],
        ['id' => 2, 'content' => 'lord']
    ];
```

When I pass it to laravel blade. here is my code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @foreach($list as $key => $position)
                <x-list :position="$position"/>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have component name it `<x-list/>` with a prop position, and here is the code of my x-list component

```
<div class="red w-60 mb-1">
    <div x-data="positionData()" class="relative">
        <button @click="submit()" class="p-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>;
    var position = @json($position);
    function positionData() {
        return {    
            submit() {
                console.log(position);
            },
        };
    }
</script>
```

It is just very simple code but when I click the submit button, the data I get is the last position
from the list `['id' => 2, 'content' => 'lord']`, even I click position 1 the data I get is still position 2 data. I don't know what happen now. I try to search it in google to fix it but I can't find the right answer on this.

Comment: sorry. I change the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue in this case is that the `positionData` function is being overwritten on each iteration of `x-list` (since each of the components is creating a new `window.positionData` function).

To solve it you could do:

```html
<div class="red w-60 mb-1">
    <div x-data="positionData(@json($position))" class="relative">
        <button @click="submit()" class="p-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>;
    function positionData(position) {
        return {    
            submit() {
                console.log(position);
            },
        };
    }
</script>
```

Specifically, you should probably move the `<script></script>` out of the `x-list` component so that it doesn't get re-created for each component (it should only be added to the page once).